# Selecting most recent result from MySQL where there are more than 1 rows matching ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm using wordpress with some custom fields, to cut this short, im echoing out all rows that have the meta_key of post_author that arent empty and grouping likewise names together otherwise i might get Pete, Steve, Pete - when all i need is Pete, Steve. Below is the SQL that makes that work

```
$wpAuthors = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(meta_value)
FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value !='' AND meta_key = 'post_author'
ORDER BY meta_key ASC"));
```

That works great. But **what if i change the author FROM pete TO steve?** Of course **wordpress** makes a duplicate entry for that post id, with a different Custom field row id. (Post ID on both rows would be something like 1100 while entry rows might be 3000 and 3001). Now the issue here is that my script still works, because both Pete and Steve are entered into the database in the correct column, but what i need it to do now is to select the most recent copy of that post id row to get the most recent author, does that make sense? I hope so!

Comment: Is it still a list of authors you want?

Do you want a list of authors with their most recent post id?

What output do you want, then maybe someone can help with the SQL.

Comment: I've already said what i'm after. My current sql gets all the authors, irrespective of who is matched to what post, i just want it to show the most recent author on posts with the same ID, which will in turn still display all the authors, just not duplicates nor authors that aren't the current active author on a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);` Add this variable in to wp-config.php, it will prevent wordpress to create post revisions.

After that install this plugin `http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/screenshots/`.

Now remove all post revisions using above wp-optimize plugin.

Comment: Does that then only show published stuff and wont repeat my postmeta rows depending on the author that gets changed etc?

Comment: No was just asking, i dont want to ruin my site if this answer isnt what im asking for. I was just double checking you understood what i was asking. I will try in a minute

Comment: well that seems to have worked a treat. 2 secs while i run the cleanup thing